# Systematically getting WMS from GeoTIFF image in GeoServer environment

Tags: geoserver, wms

Context:

I have a WebGIS system that use Postgres and NodeJS backend; JavaScript front end (using WebIX library + Leaflet); the server run on Ubuntu

I have a module that display drone images in the WebGIS. It provides the user with a list of images that has been uploaded to the server. The user can select an image on the list and load it to the webmap interface. We use GeoServer to publish WMS (of GeoTIFF image) and use the WMS to display in the interface.

Our current workflow is like this

1. User use an interface to upload drone image (GeoTIFF format) to a folder in the Ubuntu server, let called it \drone_image
   The interface ask user to enter metadata: image date, flying hight, user name, drone id.
   We also rename the image using an nameing convention.
2. The result of step 1 are:
   i) image is uploaded to the folder \drone_image\ ;
   ii) the metadata is inserted in to a postgres table called tbl_drone_image. This table have a fild name image_wms_url
3. We then need to go to GeoServer and publish the image WMS manually, then copy the WMS URL and paste it to the corresponding record in the image_wms_url field in the tbl_donre_image table.

So far we can do step 1 and 2 sucesfully. We would like to write a function that automate step 3:

- the function will: i) automaticlly go to GeoServer and publish the WMS of a given image, ii) write the WMS URL to the corresponding record on drone_image_table. Acually the difficult part is the 1st part of the function; the 2nd part is quite easy.

I guess GeoServer will have some sort of API or method to interact with it systematically but so far I did not find any clear document/ instruction yet. Any hints?

Comment: You are looking for the REST API, it's in the manual and the subject of many questions here